# Dual Display on Computer

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an AMD PC.

I want to use both the motherboard and graphics card's VGA ports for my monitors, the graphics card only has 1 VGA port.

When I plug a monitor into the motherboard VGA it picks up it's connected; however, the computer doesn't pick up the monitor.

Is there a BIOS fix? AMD Radeon Software fix?

Comment: Can you provide motherboard details?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/c1olpo